# Saving dictionary into NSUserDefaults

Tags: swift, xcode6

```
class AddElementVC: UIViewController {

    // textfields and some other functions are defined here 

    @IBAction func addElement(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        let newElement = Element(/* properties are defined here */)
        var theDict = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryForKey(tableViewData) as [String: [Element]]

        if var theArray = theDict[newElement.someProperty] {
            theArray += newElement
            theDict[newElement.someProperty] = elementArray
        } else{
            theDict[newElement.someProperty] = [newElement]
        }

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(theDict, forKey: tableViewData)

    }
}
```

**EXPLAINATION OF THE CODE ABOVE:**

My tableView-app receives its data from a dictionary of type [String: [Element]] (Element is a custom class), which is loaded from the userDefaults. In a second viewController you can fill out some textFields and finally press a UIBarButtonItem. From the textFields' data a new instance of the class "Element" is created and added to "theDict" at the key of one of the "newElement"'s properties. All that works fine as I checked it with console-outputs, but I am not able to finally save the edited dictionary in the userDefaults. There are no syntax-errors, but when I use the app and try to to add another element to the Dictionary via the second viewController, the following error is displayed:

**ERROR-MESSAGE:**

NSForwarding: warning: object 0xdcb002c of class '_TtC12myApp7Element' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead

Researches didn't help me to understand the error-message.

**EDIT**

```
import Foundation

class Element: NSCoding {

enum State: String {
    case state1 = "state1"
    case state2 = "state2"
}

let state: State
// some more properties

init(state: String /* something more */ ){
    self.state = State.fromRaw(state)!
    // something more
}

init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
    self.state = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("state") // displays error: 'AnyObject' is not convertible to 'Element.State'
    // something more
}

func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder!) {
    aCoder.encodeObject(self.state, forKey: "state") // displays error: Extra Argument 'forKey' in call
    // something more
}

}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [NSUserDefaults documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsuserdefaults_class/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/setObject:forKey:):

> The value parameter can be only property list objects: NSData,
>   NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. For NSArray and
>   NSDictionary objects, their contents must be property list objects.
>   See [“What is a Property List?”](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH3-54303) in [Property List Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i).

You cannot store a dictionary with elements of `Element` in the dictionary.

One option is to make sure `Element` implements the [NSCoding protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and then use [NSKeyedArchiver](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to convert your dictionary into NSData:

```
// Storing the dictionary
var data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(theDict)
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(data, forKey: tableViewData)

// Retrieving the dictionary
var outData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dataForKey(tableViewData)
var dict = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(outData)
```

Your protocol implementation would look like something like this:

```
init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
    self.state = State.fromRaw(aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("state") as String)
}

func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder!) {
    aCoder.encodeObject(self.state.toRaw(), forKey: "state")
}
```

You cannot store an Enum, but you can store the raw representation of it which is a string.

Comment: thank you very much. But as I am really new to iOS dev I seem to be incapable of implementing this protocol correctly. Might you take a look at my attempt which is attached to my question above, please

Comment: @NickPodratz What error / problems are you running into with implementing the protocol?

Comment: state = State.fromRaw(aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("state") as String)!
this way it works. But the initial error message remains and the app crashes.

Comment: You must bridge with `@objc`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24659609/how-to-archive-and-unarchive-custom-objects-in-swift-or-how-to-save-custom-obje?rq=1

Comment: Remark: the raw representation of an Enum is not always a String.