# Swift: Arrays with multiple values out of plist

Tags: swift, nsarray, plist

since Swift it is possible to create arrays with multiple values like

```
myArray = [ String : Boolean ]
```

i want to create an array like this out of a plist, but it seems not possible in the xcode-editor to create an array like this (you can only save one single value per array-index). any ideas?

Comment: `[ String : Boolean ]` is the type of a *dictionary*, not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can save arrays with other collection types inside - other arrays, tuples, dictionaries, objects, etc.  Just one example for a playground:

```
import Foundation

let a: [Int] = [1,2,3,4]
let b: [String] = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

let c = [a, b]

println(c[0])

/*

(
1,
2,
3,
4
)

*/

println(c[1])

/*
(
a,
b,
c,
d
)
```

for your plist you could do this:

```
let a = [1,"a"]
let b = [2, "b"]

let c = [a, b]

println(c[0])

/*

(
1,
a
)

*/

println(c[1])

/*
(
(
2,
b
)
*/
```

if you use NSCoding, you prearrange all the data any way you want and get back in that form.

[NSUserDefaults - How can I store an array of custom objects (Goals)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26172620/nsuserdefaults-how-can-i-store-an-array-of-custom-objects-goals/26173098#26173098)

Answer (score 0):

You can store any number of value in swift array.Just use

```
var myArray:[[AnyObject]] = []
myArray.append([1,2,"abc"])   //store at 0 index
```

The above example is array of `AnyObject` arrays so you can store any kind of value.You can make array of `Dictionaries`

In your code you are referring to `Dictionary` not `array`.

To store in `plist` you have to use `NSDictionary`
refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25172186/1881472)