# Swift save cutom class in settings exception: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -length only defined for abstract class

Tags: swift, settings, nscoding

Hello I try to store a custom object with NSUserDefaults. I used this helpful post [Saving custom SWIFT class with NSCoding to UserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26469457/saving-custom-swift-class-with-nscoding-to-userdefaults)

But I get the following exception when I try it out

> 2015-05-12 11:05:14.994 KirchnerTime[4424:75095] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -length only defined for abstract class.  Define -[Project length]!'

```
import Foundation

@objc(Project)
public class ProjectJobEntity: NSData, NSCoding  
{
private let _barCode: String
private var _projectNumber: String
private var _projectDescription: String
private var _jobDescription: String

public var BarCode: String
{
    get { return self._barCode }
}

public var ProjectNumber: String
{
    get { return self._projectNumber }
    set { self._projectNumber = newValue }
}

public var ProjectDescription: String
{
    get { return self._projectDescription }
    set { self._projectDescription = newValue }
}

public var JobDescription: String
{
    get { return self._jobDescription }
    set { self._jobDescription = newValue }
}

public init(barCode: String, projectNumber: String, projectDescription: String, jobDescription: String)
{
    self._barCode = barCode
    self._projectNumber = projectNumber
    self._projectDescription = projectDescription
    self._jobDescription = jobDescription

    super.init()
}


public init(barCode: String)
{
    self._barCode = barCode
    self._projectNumber = ""
    self._projectDescription = ""
    self._jobDescription = ""

    super.init()
}

override public func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder)
{
    aCoder.encodeObject(self._barCode, forKey: "barCode")
    aCoder.encodeObject(self._projectNumber, forKey: "projectNumber")
    aCoder.encodeObject(self._projectDescription, forKey: "projectDescription")
    aCoder.encodeObject(self._jobDescription, forKey: "jobDescription")
}

required public init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
{
    self._barCode = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("barCode") as! String
    self._projectNumber = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("projectNumber") as! String
    self._projectDescription = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("projectDescription") as! String
    self._jobDescription = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("jobDescription") as! String

    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

this is the object which should be stored.

```
 public func saveSettings()
{
    let settings = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    settings.setValue(self._cardNumber, forKeyPath: cardNumberKey)

    settings.setObject(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(ProjectJobEntity(barCode: "Test")), forKey: "Project")
}
```

and this is how I try it.

Answer (score 0):

I had same exception.

I use NSObject as parent class.

use under code

```
    public class ProjectJobEntity: NSObject
    {
        private let _barCode: String
        private var _projectNumber: String
        private var _projectDescription: String
        private var _jobDescription: String

        public var BarCode: String
            {
            get { return self._barCode }
        }

        public var ProjectNumber: String
            {
            get { return self._projectNumber }
            set { self._projectNumber = newValue }
        }

        public var ProjectDescription: String
            {
            get { return self._projectDescription }
            set { self._projectDescription = newValue }
        }

        public var JobDescription: String
            {
            get { return self._jobDescription }
            set { self._jobDescription = newValue }
        }

        public init(barCode: String, projectNumber: String, projectDescription: String, jobDescription: String)
        {
            self._barCode = barCode
            self._projectNumber = projectNumber
            self._projectDescription = projectDescription
            self._jobDescription = jobDescription

            super.init()
        }


        public init(barCode: String)
        {
            self._barCode = barCode
            self._projectNumber = ""
            self._projectDescription = ""
            self._jobDescription = ""

            super.init()
        }

        public func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder)
        {
            aCoder.encodeObject(self._barCode, forKey: "barCode")
            aCoder.encodeObject(self._projectNumber, forKey: "projectNumber")
            aCoder.encodeObject(self._projectDescription, forKey: "projectDescription")
            aCoder.encodeObject(self._jobDescription, forKey: "jobDescription")
        }

        public func initWithCoder(aDecoder: NSCoder) -> ProjectJobEntity
        {
            let barCode = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("barCode") as! String
            let projectNumber = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("projectNumber") as! String
            let projectDescription = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("projectDescription") as! String
            let jobDescription = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("jobDescription") as! String

            return ProjectJobEntity(barCode: barCode, projectNumber: projectNumber, projectDescription: projectDescription, jobDescription: jobDescription)
        }
    }
```