# Save Custom Class Array With NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nsuserdefaults

I have a custom class called Friend:

```
class Friend {

    var fullName: String
    var birthday: String
    var from: String

    var photoLink: String = ""
    var photo: UIImage = UIImage()
    var photos: [AnyObject] = [AnyObject]()

    init(fullname: String, birthday: String, gotFrom: String) {
        self.fullName = fullname
        self.birthday = birthday
        self.from = gotFrom
    }
}
```

I've tried saving it with NSUserDefaults but I get an error because I use a custom Class.

How can I save an array of Friend?

Comment: your class should implement NSCoding protocol...

Comment: Check this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26469457/saving-custom-swift-class-with-nscoding-to-userdefaults

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315948/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-nsuserdefaults

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the simple example for you to save and retrive class from `NSUserDefaults`:

```
    //your class
    class Person: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var name: String!
    var age: Int!
    required convenience init(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        self.init()
        self.name = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("name") as! String
        self.age = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("age") as! Int
    }
    convenience init(name: String, age: Int) {
        self.init()
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }
    func encodeWithCoder(coder: NSCoder) {
        if let name = name { coder.encodeObject(name, forKey: "name") }
        if let age = age { coder.encodeObject(age, forKey: "age") }


        }

    }

//store values in class and store it to NSUserDefaults
var newPerson = [Person]()
newPerson.append(Person(name: "Leo", age: 45))
newPerson.append(Person(name: "Dharmesh", age: 25))
let personData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(newPerson)
NSUserDefaults().setObject(personData, forKey: "personData")

//retrive your values
if let loadedData = NSUserDefaults().dataForKey("personData") {
    loadedData
    if let loadedPerson = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(loadedData) as? [Person] {
        loadedPerson[0].name   //"Leo"
        loadedPerson[0].age    //45
    }
}
```

Tested with playground.

Hope this example will help.

Comment: What is Custom class contains UIImage type var?
Can we store that in UserDefaults?

Comment: I would not suggest to store `UIImage` into `UserDefaults`

Comment: okay.
Should we store Data of UIIMage?

Comment: yes you can store but use document directory to store images.

Comment: hmmm okay. thank you